# Multiple Selection With Checkbox for Data Subsetting In R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to show only selected checkbox data to render on UI from checkbox panel, where first three check box are mutually exclusive to each other (i.e one can only select one out of first three & can select number of KPI from checkbox option) in shiny app but struggling to fix this. Basis on the user selection in check box the plot should change automatically for an example the separate line plots between MO_ID & number of selected KPI vertically for each select drug or Manufacturer or drug class. I tried to to do this below is my code your help will highly appreciated

DrugData.csv

```
MO_ID   capture_rate_high_adj   NBRx_adjusted_high_share    Total_adjusted_high_share   TRx_baseline_low_share  DrugType    DrugClass   MANUFACTURER        date    goal1completions    goal
1212016 0.097167749 0.020752878 0.003667932 0.00225614  DRUG 1  ART Manufacturer5       1012016 4   goal1
1612011 0.216740195 0.041761676 0.008145028 0.004881227 DRUG 1  II  Manufacturer4       1012016 10  goal2
10112016    0.679445079 0.13818709  0.033960635 0.020129843 DRUG 1  NNRTI   Manufacturer3       1012016 8   goal3
512016  0.532274828 0.113680095 0.030975403 0.018364531 DRUG 2  PI  Manufacturer2       1012016 13  goal5
1012015 0.541738943 0.122225515 0.036405199 0.021408197 DRUG 3  STR Manufacturer1       1012016 6   goal4
1012015 0.323315694 0.08475766  0.026376663 0.015392466 DRUG 4  NNRTI   Manufacturer5       1012016 12  goal7
1012014 0.426477779 0.100488819 0.034437931 0.020072081 DRUG 1  PI  Manufacturer4       1012016 7   goal6
1012016 0.627661362 0.146335677 0.052207204 0.030324811 DRUG 2  STR Manufacturer3       1012016 12  goal6
2712016 0.682537914 0.173016511 0.067592392 0.039461229 DRUG 3  NNRTI   Manufacturer2       1012016 10  goal7
1712016 0.395454954 0.106938038 0.043405249 0.025173052 DRUG 4  PI  Manufacturer1       1012016 10  goal8
1012016 0.405448121 0.097840719 0.042806791 0.024596638 DRUG 1  STR Manufacturer5       1012016 10  goal9
1812016 0.61654553  0.154245245 0.080707769 0.046582374 DRUG 2  NNRTI   Manufacturer4       1012016 10  goal10
1912016 0.448994855 0.082140864 0.049786133 0.028663422 DRUG 3  PI  Manufacturer3       1012016 10  goal11
2012016 0.563174269 0.103926623 0.06641121  0.038270423 DRUG 4  STR Manufacturer2       1012016 10  goal12
2112016 0.294613984 0.062050611 0.041020625 0.023675833 DRUG 1  ART Manufacturer1       1012016 10  goal13
2212016 0.408718205 0.075283165 0.0575669   0.03282064  DRUG 2  II  Manufacturer5       1012016 10  goal14
2312016 0.111911856 0.018734629 0.015831974 0.009130108 DRUG 3  NNRTI   Manufacturer4       1012016 10  goal15
2412016 0.150495864 0.026025458 0.024094392 0.013900663 DRUG 4  PI  Manufacturer3       1012016 10  goal16
```

My Code

I also tried to select any file .csv file in same format from a folder through a drop down menu to change the data for analysis, but some how it's not working. Many thanks for help in advance.

```
###############Assigning Packages
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(rhandsontable)

#############################
# Importing Data
cDat <- read.table(file = "data/DrugData.csv", sep = ",",  header =

                 TRUE, row.names = NULL)
cDat1 <- read.table(file = "data/DrugData1.csv", sep = ",",  header =

                 TRUE, row.names = NULL)
DF <- read.csv("/Users/anshulujlayan/Documents/output.csv", sep=",", 
 row.names=1)
    #( DF <- data.frame(Value = 1:10, Name = LETTERS[1:10],
    #                   Date = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out =     10),
 #                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) )
    editTable(DF, outdir="/Users/anshulujlayan/Documents",         outfilename="newaakritiDF")
############################
    #filenames <- list.files(path = "input$files[['data/']]", pattern=     "*.csv" )
    folder <-         "/Users/anshulujlayan/Documents/Team_Profile/First_Assignement_29_September_2017    /data"      # path to folder that holds multiple .csv files
filenames <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv")
print(filenames)


print(DF)
MANUFACTURER_list <- unique(cDat$MANUFACTURER)
DrugClass_list <- unique(cDat$DrugClass)
DrugType_list <- unique(cDat$DrugType)
columns <- names(cDat)
abc <- cDat$MO_ID

d <- as.character(cDat$MO_ID)
d <-  paste0(substr(d, 0, 2), "-", substr(d, 3, 4), "-", substr(d, start = 4, 7))
cDat$MO_ID <- as.Date(d, format = "%d-%m-%y")
mno <- cDat$filteredData
HL_list <- c("High","low")
print(mno)

editTable <- function(DF, outdir=getwd(), outfilename="newAakritiDF"){
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  ## Handsontable
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
      values[["previous"]] <- isolate(values[["DF"]])
      DF = hot_to_r(input$hot)
    } else {
      if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
    DF <- DF
      else
    DF <- values[["DF"]]
    }
    values[["DF"]] <- DF
  })

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    DF <- values[["DF"]]

    rhandsontable(DF)
  })

  ## Save
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    fileType <- isolate(input$fileType)
    finalDF <- isolate(values[["DF"]])
    dput(finalDF, file=file.path(outdir, sprintf("%s.txt", outfilename)))
    # saveRDS(finalDF, file=file.path(outdir, sprintf("%s.rds",     outfilename)))
  }
  )



  inputdata <- reactive({
    if (grepl("[/\\\\]", input$dataset)) {
      stop("Invalid dataset")
    }
    read.csv(file.path("folder", input$dataset))
  })

  filteredData <- reactive({
    cDat %>% filter(MANUFACTURER %in% input$campaign &
                  DrugClass %in% input$campaign1 &
                  DrugType %in% input$campaign2 )
  })


  selectedData <- reactive({
    filteredData() %>% 
      select_(.dots = input$columns)
  })

  output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
    selectedData()


  })



  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      "DrugDataab.csv"
    },

    content = function(file) {
      write.table(x = selectedData(),
              file = file,
              quote = FALSE, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
    }
  ) 
  observe({
    if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL) 
    else if (input$selectall%%2 == 0)
    {
              updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaign","",choices=MANUFACTURER_list)
    }
    else
    {
                  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaign","",choices=MANUFACTURER_list,selecte    d=MANUFACTURER_list)
    }
  })

  observe({
    if(input$selectall2 == 0) return(NULL) 
    else if (input$selectall2%%2 == 0)
    {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaign1","",choices=DrugClass_list)
    }
    else
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaign1","",choices=DrugClass_list,selected=    DrugClass_list)
    }
  })

  observe({
    if(input$selectall3 == 0) return(NULL) 
    else if (input$selectall3%%2 == 0)
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaign2","",choices=DrugType_list)
    }
    else
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"campaign2","",choices=DrugType_list,selected=D    rugType_list)
    }
  })


  observe({
    if(input$selectall4 == 0) return(NULL) 
    else if (input$selectall4%%2 == 0)
    {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"columns","",choices=columns)
    }
    else
{
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"columns","",choices=columns,selected=columns)
    }
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(cDat, x = ~abc, y = ~columns)
  })

  filterednewData <- reactive({ 
    # no need for "filter"
    cDat[cDat$MANUFACTURER %in% input$checkGroup, ]
  })

  output$Conversionrate1 <- renderPlotly({
    # use filteredData() instead of the full dataset
    plot_ly(
      filteredData(),  
      x = ~MO_ID,
      y = ~goal1completions,
      split = ~MANUFACTURER,
      mode = "lines + markers",
      hoverinfo = "y" # "y" instead of y ... at least in the newest version
    ) 
  })

}


####################### UI.R ##############


ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Forecasting Engine"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(style = "background-color: #98d8c6",

             fluidRow(


               column(6,
                      h6(style = "font-weight: bold;color: #275c4d","Manufacture"),
                      div(style = "height: 200px; background-color:white; max-height: 200px; border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.52); padding-left: 10px",
                          br(),
                          checkboxGroupInput('campaign', 'Manufacturer',
                                             MANUFACTURER_list,
                                             selected = MANUFACTURER_list)

                      )
               ),
               column(6,
                      h6(style = "font-weight: bold;color: #275c4d","Drug Class"),
                      div(style = "overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 200px; min-height: 200px; background-color:white;padding-left: 10px;border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.52);",
                          checkboxGroupInput('campaign1', 'DrugClass',
                                             DrugClass_list,
                                             selected = DrugClass_list)

                      )
               )
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(6, 
                      h6(style = "font-weight: bold;color: #275c4d","Drug List"),
                      div(style = "overflow-y:scroll;border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.52); max-height: 200px; min-height: 200px; background-color:white; padding-left: 10px",
                          br(),
                          checkboxGroupInput('campaign2', 'DrugType',
                                             DrugType_list,
                                             selected = DrugType_list))),
               column(6,
                      h6(style = "font-weight: bold;color: #275c4d","KPI"),
                      div(style = "overflow-y:scroll;border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.52); max-height: 200px; min-height: 200px; background-color:white;padding-left: 10px",
                          # checkboxGroupInput("columns","Select Columns",choices=vchoices,inline = T)
                          checkboxGroupInput('columns', 'Columns',
                                             columns,
                                             selected = columns))



               )),br(),

             fluidRow(
               column(3,actionLink(style="background-color: #275c4d;color: #fff;width: 150px","selectall","ALL")),
               column(3,actionLink(style="background-color: #275c4d;color: #fff;width: 50px","selectall2","RESET")),
               column(3,actionLink(style="background-color: #275c4d;color: #fff;width: 50px","selectall3","ALL")),
               column(3,actionLink(style="background-color: #275c4d;color: #fff;width: 50px","selectall4","RESET"))
             ),br(),
             actionButton(style="background-color: #275c4d;color: #fff;width: 150px","","CDAT"),
             actionButton(style="background-color: #275c4d;color: #fff;width: 150px","","CDAT1"),

             fluidRow(
               column(style = "margin-top: 30px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 10px",6,"","Select Frequency"),
               column(6,
                      selectInput("analysis", label = "", 
                                  c("Monthly" = "all",
                                    "Yearly" = "specific"),
                                  selected = "all")

               )        ),br(),

                 fluidRow(
                   column(style = "font-weight: bold;line-height:     10px",6,"Select Scenerio",

                      selectInput(
                        "subsetType", "",
                        c("Monthly" = "all",
                          "Yearly" = "specific"),
                        selected = "all") 

               ),
               column(6,
                          div(style = "overflow-y:scroll;border: 1px solid     rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.52); max-height: 50px; min-height: 50px; background-    color:white; padding-left: 10px",

                              checkboxGroupInput('campaign5', '',
                                             HL_list,
                                                 selected = HL_list))

                   )        ),

                 fluidRow(
                   column(style = "font-weight: bold;line-height: 10px",6,
                          actionButton(style="background-color: #275c4d;text-    align:center;color: grey;width: 200px","selectall5","View Final Forecast")
               ),
                   column(6,
                          div(style = "font-weight: bold;line-height: 10px",
                              actionButton(style="background-color:     #275c4d;color: grey;width: 200px","selectall6","View Baseline Forecast")
                      )     )),


                 downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data"),
                 #   checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Goal"), 
                 #                     setNames(object = paste0("Manufacturer", 1:5), 
                 #                             nm = paste0("Manufacturer ",     1:5)),
                 #                   selected = "Manufacturer 1"),
                 selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                             label = "Choose platform annotation file",
                             choices = c("cDat","pressure"))


    ),

    ##### Show data in Main Panel  
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput('mytable1'),     dataTableOutput('mytable2')),
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotlyOutput("Conversionrate1"),
                           verbatimTextOutput("event")),
                  tabPanel("Editable Parameter", br(),actionButton("save",     "Save"), br(),
                           rHandsontableOutput("hot"))

      ))



  )
    )
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Is that somewhat what you are looking for?

Comment: I just updated my code what I trying to have through this as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` `filter` with `%in%` operator.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Change rownames
cDat <- read.table(file.path(DATA_DIR, "DrugData.csv"), sep = ",",  header = 
                     TRUE, row.names = NULL)
campaigns_list <- unique(cDat$MANUFACTURER)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
    #cDat[input$campaign_list,]
    #print(input)
    cDat %>% filter(MANUFACTURER %in% input$campaign)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Example"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput('campaign', 'Manufacturer',
                         campaigns_list,
                         selected = campaigns_list)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('mytable1'))
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If we need to use the checkbox for column values and column name as in the given data set column names are "MO_ID   DrugType MANUFACTURER   Revenue DrugClass" and then check box should work as per click. I tried puting the name of the column as a list or array to pass in same way but not able solve the same.

Comment: I also wants to draw a plot basis on the selection through checkbox in tab, is there a direct way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

with using the package `dplyr`is this quite easy. Just change your code like this.

```
###############Assigning Packages
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

#############################
# Importing Data
cDat <- read.table(file = "data/DrugData.tsv", sep = ",",  header = 
                     TRUE, row.names = NULL)
############################

###### Preparing list for Checkbox & Change rownames
#campaigns_list <- unique(cDat$MANUFACTURER)

MANUFACTURER_list <- unique(cDat$MANUFACTURER)
DrugClass_list <- unique(cDat$DrugClass)
DrugType_list <- unique(cDat$DrugType)
columns <- names(cDat)
####################### Server.R##########
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filteredData <- reactive({
    cDat %>% filter(MANUFACTURER %in% input$campaign &
                      DrugClass %in% input$campaign1 &
                      DrugType %in% input$campaign2 )
  })


  selectedData <- reactive({
    filteredData() %>% 
      select_(.dots = input$columns)
  })
  output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
    selectedData()
  })
}


####################### UI.R ##############
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Example"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput('campaign', 'Manufacturer',
                         MANUFACTURER_list,
                         selected = MANUFACTURER_list),
      checkboxGroupInput('campaign1', 'DrugClass',
                         DrugClass_list,
                         selected = DrugClass_list),
      checkboxGroupInput('campaign2', 'DrugType',
                         DrugType_list,
                         selected = DrugType_list),
      checkboxGroupInput('columns', 'Columns',
                         columns,
                         selected = columns)
    ),

    ##### Show data in Main Panel  
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('mytable1'))
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: You can see the same answer posted above.

Comment: it's not helping me at all

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what is not working.

Comment: I have updated my answer it is more what you are looking for??

Comment: Thanks a lot Bertil it's working fine for manufacturer & the column in the dataset. When I am adding one more along with Manufacturer for filtering through check box (i.e DrugType & Drugclass). The table is not updated in main panel based on selection of the values. I also wanted to pass the selection of values for plots between  MO_ID & Revenue for different drug type & drug class (line chart or scatter plot) in separate tab in main panel. Many thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You want to add one column to filter from?

Comment: I have added DrugClass_list <- unique(cDat$DrugClass) and filteredData <- reactive({
    cDat %<>% filter(DrugClass %in% input$campaign1)
  }). In same way as you did.

Comment: could you please update your code with what you have tried.

Comment: Hi @Avyan , you were redifining the filteredData thats why is was only listening to one input. I have putted all the filters in one function and it works well. I have updated my code.

Comment: Yes it working great for me, please suggest for the second part if Manufacturer, Drug Class and Drug List are exclusive of each other, which means if selection is made in one box, selection of the other two will be disabled. Each variable like revenue...in data  option will be displayed in one chart corresponding to MO_ID (i.e time variable). The number of charts correspond to the number of selected numeric columns in the data set